# Neovim `:terminal` not reading .bash_profile

Tags: neovim

When I start a terminal with the `:terminal` command, I get this output:

```
++ parse_git_branch
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
~ $
```

`parse_git_branch` is a bash function defined in my `.bash_profile` that I use for a custom prompt:

```
export PS1="\\[\\033[33;1m\\]\\w\\[\\033[m\\]\$(parse_git_branch || echo unknown)\\[\\033[00m\\] $ "
```

Why does neovim not read the `.bash_profile`?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I'll take a crack at this though I'm purely a Vim user.*

If you look at `man bash` you'll find the rules bash uses to load the various startup files.

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order,

So you need to start a login shell...

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
>   one started with the --login option.

So adding `--login` to the bash command that neovim uses should do what you want. (Assuming it's the same as vim that can be specified with something like `let &shell='/usr/bin/bash --login'` in neovim init file.)

Alternatively, `--rcfile path-to-bash-profile` can probably be used instead of `--login`. The difference between the two is subtle and for most in-vim use they are effectively equivalent. I mention both in the unlikely event someone is doing something sensitive to whether the terminal is a login shell or not in which case they can try the alternative.

Comment: "I'll not go into whether a login shell is appropriate for this usage or whether you should be putting functions in .bash_profile" -- I would appreciate your advice on those things regardless

Comment: Don't worry too much about it, I wasn't suggesting you were doing something seriously wrong. But, for example, a function defined in `.bash_profile` won't be visible in an interactive subshell (e.g. run `bash` from bash command line). `.bashrc` is executed for that scenario. Common pattern is to source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`...but that's not a perfect solution either. Come to think of it I might just remove that from my answer...likely to be a distraction more than anything.

Comment: FYI, I'm glad you added the `--rcfile` note, because the `--login` version broke an unrelated plugin, but the rcfile version did not.

Comment: Ah, perhaps my original warning about login shells and bash_profile _was_ prudent. What's the plugin and how did it break, if I may?

Comment: fugitive broke.  Gstatus command was showing an empty window